# 'Object doesn't support this property or method error' while using Index-Match for Data Validation Drop Down

Tags: excel, vba

I have a micro in which I am using a simple `INDEX-MATCH`formula to select a `string` variable from a drop-down list. The `INDEX-MATCH` columns are in `Sheet1` and the Data Validation list is in `Sheet2`. Running the micro results in an error `Object doesn't support this property or method`and highlights the row  `cel2.Offset(0, 2).Validate = coresVal`.

`Sheet2` has a `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(___)` as the `Sub` with only selected cells triggering the change in `Sheet2` if that might be causing an error, I don't know. Am I doing something wrong with the code below? I tried to see if both the variables, `coresVal` and the `INDEX-MATCH` formula are of the same type and it shows both of them as `strings`. What is the reason that I am getting this error?

```
Option Explicit
'using a constant to store the highlight color...
Const HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = 9894500 'RGB(100, 250, 150)'Is a cell highlighted? 
EDIT: changed the function name to IsHighlighted

Sub Asign_Bided()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim cel1 As Range
Dim cel2 As Range
Dim Bid As Range
Dim line As Range
Dim OffEmp As Range
Dim BidL8 As Range
Dim BidL8E As Range
Dim coresVal As String

'This sheet has the table from which INDEX-MATCH should be pulling the employee name
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

'This is the sheet where the name should be selected from Data Validation drop-down
'and it also has a "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal  Target AS Range)"
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

'Range("Sheet2!B12:B40,Sheet2!B43:B58,Sheet2!B61:B77,Sheet2!B81:B97,Sheet2!B101:B117)
Set line = ws2.Range("All_Pos_Hilight_Mon") 
Set OffEmp = ws2.Range("$B$151:$B$210")

'Below Ranges are in a Table with two columns Employee and Position in Sheet1;
Set BidL8 = ws1.Range("Bided_Pos_T[Bided_Prep_Position]")
Set BidL8E = ws1.Range("Bided_Pos_T[Employee]")

ws2.Activate
For Each cel2 In line
    If IsHighlighted(cel2) Then
        For Each cel1 In BidL8E
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(OffEmp, cel1.Value) > 0 Then
            Else:   coresVal = "=INDEX(Bided_Pos_T[Employee],MATCH(Butter_8_Prep_Mon,Bided_Pos_T[Bided_Prep_Position],0))"
                    Debug.Print coresVal
                    cel2.Offset(0, 2).Validate = coresVal
            End If
        Next cel1
    End If
Next cel2
End Sub
Function IsHighlighted(c As Range)
'Function to check if that particular cell is highlighted
    IsHighlighted = (c.Interior.Color = HIGHLIGHT_COLOR)
End Function
```

The expected result here is that the name of the employee from the table should be stored in `coresVal` and after `cel2` is `offset` it should `Validate` that name in Sheet2. I tried using `Evaluate` function as well.

Example: `coresVal = Evaluate ("INDEX (" & BidL8E.Address &",MATCH(cel2.Value, " & BidL8.Address &"))")`

The result was that it was shooting the error type mismatch and highlighting the Evaluate line.
Is there any solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Validate` is not a property of the Range object

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure what is `cel2.Offset(0, 2).Validate = coresVal` suppose to be, maybe you meant `cel2.Offset(0, 2).Value = coresVal` ?

Anyway, you have some syntax error in your `Evaluate` Formula String.

For setting columns in a table (`ListObject`), I rather use the setting of the objects like in the code below:

```
Dim Tbl As ListObject

Set Tbl = ws1.ListObjects("Bided_Pos_T")

Set BidL8 = Tbl.ListColumns("Bided_Prep_Position").DataBodyRange
Set BidL8E = Tbl.ListColumns("Employee").DataBodyRange
```

Then, as for your `Evaluate` line, you need to use something line the string below:

```
coresVal = Evaluate("INDEX(" & BidL8E.Address(0, 0, xlA1, xlExternal) & _
                        ",MATCH(" & cel2.Value & "," & BidL8.Address(0, 0, xlA1, xlExternal) & ",0))")
```

As your 2 Ranges `BidL8E` and `BidL8` are not in `"Sheet1"` and `cel2` range loops through `line` which is in `"Sheet1"`, so you need to specify the 4th parameter of the `Range.Address` function, see [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address)

**However**, you also need to set an Error handling scenario, in case the `MATCH` section inside the `Index` fails.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to clarify, `cel2.Offset(0,2).Validate = coresVal` was to select the `coresVal` from the `INDEX-MATCH` function, shift the selection and select the value from the drop-down. I am trying your answer right now. Will comment if I face any trouble. I would also like to know how to set the `Error` scenario. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, so I tried the code, but it is still giving me a type mismatch error and highlighting the `Evaluate` function line.

Comment: If you add a line `Debug.Print "INDEX(" & BidL8E.Address(0, 0, xlA1, xlExternal) & ",MATCH(" & cel2.Value & "," & BidL8.Address(0, 0, xlA1, xlExternal) & ",0))"`, what are you getting in the immediate window ?

Comment: Hey, so adding the `Debug.Print` I get around 200 rows of this `INDEX('[First Shift Tempelate.xlsm]OT_Table'!S27:S263,MATCH(Toppings_12,'[First Shift Tempelate.xlsm]OT_Table'!R27:R263,0))`. Here `OT_Table` is `Sheet1` in the code above.

Comment: The `Match` function, however, iterates through all the values in the columns `BidL8`, but shows only `Toppings_12` in the `Match` function. Not able to understand why.

Comment: Any idea what might be the problem?